# update each groups of rows with different value in one query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table structure like this
[image]

and a php array as shown below

```
$assign=array("sFirst"=>array("101","102","103"),"sSecond"=>array("104","105"),"sThird"=>array("106"));
```

**my problem**
i want to update status column of the above table to 1 and the supervisor column to the key of the array where the reg_id value
exists in the array so that table look will be like this
Final table look
[image]

**my attempt**
i only know how this can be done in a single array not in a multidemsional array
as shown below

```
$sql2="update stack set status=1,supervisor='sFirst'
       where reg_id in  (" . implode(",", $assign['sFirst']) . ")";
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Check the last link of your post please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid executing queries in for loop,
following code will give single update query that will update records as expected

```
<?php

$assign=array("sFirst"=>array("101","102","103"),"sSecond"=>array("104","105"),"sThird"=>array("106"));

$supervisorUpdate = "( CASE ";
$whereArr = array();
foreach($assign as $key=>$value){
    $supervisorUpdate .= " WHEN reg_id IN (" . implode(",", $value) . ") THEN '$key' ";
    $whereArr[] = implode(",", $value);
}
$where = " WHERE reg_id IN (" . implode(",", $whereArr) . ") " ;

$supervisorUpdate .= " ELSE supervisor END )" ;

$sql = "update stack set status=1, supervisor = " . $supervisorUpdate  . $where;
```

If you echo above $sql then it will give you update query like this:

```
update stack 
set 
    status=1, 
    supervisor = ( CASE 
        WHEN reg_id IN (101,102,103) THEN 'sFirst' 
        WHEN reg_id IN (104,105) THEN 'sSecond' 
        WHEN reg_id IN (106) THEN 'sThird' 
        ELSE supervisor END ) 
WHERE reg_id IN (101,102,103,104,105,106)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
foreach ($assign as $key => $value)
{
$sql2="update stack set status=1,supervisor=$key
       where reg_id in  (" . implode(",", $value) . ")";
//execute query here
}
```

EDIT:
In not knowing another solution, and if you only want to make a single query.
You can make a loop to generate the query.
Something along the lines of this

```
$case="case "
$in=""
foreach ($assign as $key => $value)
    {
    $imploded=implode(",", $value);
    $case=$case . " when reg_id in  (" . $imploded . ") then " .$key ;
    $in= in . $imploded;
    $sql2="update stack set status=1,supervisor=" . $case . " end 
       where reg_id in  (" . $in . ")";
    }
```

You need to account for the commas as i didnt pay attention.

Comment: i appreciate your solution. but i don't want to do this in a loop, i don't know if there is any alternative

Comment: @emmyfelico Any reason for avoiding loops?

Comment: i'm thinking of it's performance effect  for instance, avolding the problem of execution time up on the server

Comment: @emmyfelico see my edited answer. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: your code was very helpful but i could not accept it because a newbie might not be able to fix the comma error which is currently making it not to work properly. thank you